# Microsoft Graph token expiring after 1 day

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, bearer-token

I'm trying to integrate Microsoft token into my app, but I have a weird bug where even if I'm refreshing the token every 30 min, it says that the token has expired after 1 day.
I'm getting the token from the user with the following code

```
const scope = e.target.dataset.scope;
var url = new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
const params = {
  client_id: '****',
  response_type: 'code',
  redirect_uri: `${Meteor.settings.public.__BASE_URL}/template/email-import`,
  scope: 'user.read mail.read mail.readbasic mail.readwrite Mail.Send',
  code_challenge: '****',
  code_challenge_method: 'plain',
  state: scope
}
        
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
window.location.replace(url);
```

And after that I catch the response with the access token and the refresh token and it gets refreshed every 30 min with the following code

```
const params = {
  client_id: '****',
  scope: 'user.read mail.read mail.readbasic mail.readwrite Mail.Send',
  redirect_uri: Meteor.settings.public.__JTI_SERVER + '/template/email-import', 
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  refresh_token: refreshToken,
}
var formData = new URLSearchParams();
for (var k in params) {
  formData.append(k, params[k]);
}
const response = await fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': Meteor.settings.public.__JTI_SERVER + '/template/email-import'
  }
})
const json = await response.json();
if(json.error) {
  throw new Error(`Error refreshing the token for company id ${company._id} and email ${company.email_details[scope].user_info.mail}`)
} else {
  Company.update(company._id, {$set: {[`email_details.${scope}.microsoft_token`]: json }})
}
```

I honestly think that I'm refreshing the token correctly as I get a different access and refresh token each time the function runs. But even with that the token seems to expire after a day and I cannot find in the settings where to change this.

The complete error log I'm getting is

```
{
error: 'invalid_grant',
error_description: 'AADSTS700081: The refresh token has expired due to maximum lifetime. The token was issued on 2021-05-23T09:51:53.7700436+00:00 and the maximum allowed lifetime for this application is 1.00:00:00.\r\n' +
'Trace ID: e0ae3ecc-1324-4ae5-823b-ed38e393a400\r\n' +
'Correlation ID: 409fd9ed-64c0-4f81-8ba7-546e6ceb2542\r\n' +
'Timestamp: 2021-05-26 07:30:01Z',
error_codes: [ 700081 ],
timestamp: '2021-05-26 07:30:01Z',
trace_id: 'e0ae3ecc-1324-4ae5-823b-ed38e393a400',
correlation_id: '409fd9ed-64c0-4f81-8ba7-546e6ceb2542',
error_uri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700081'
}
```

If someone could help with this it would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Oscar

Comment: You may want to get it started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) - you can configure the token lifetime, expiration duration etc!!

Comment: Hello @Dev thanks for your answer I saw that page, it has a warning that says "As of January 30, 2021 you can not configure refresh and session token lifetimes. Azure Active Directory no longer honors refresh and session token configuration in existing policies." and by default the expiration should be 90 days instead of 1, right? I also checked the [user sign-in frequency documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime) but also should default to 90 days and we don't have any policy created

Comment: Yes @oscar, you're welcome. Yes you're correct and that's the correct documentation. You may want to check with your administrator to see if they have any existing policies or new policies with these limits contributing to it.

Comment: @Dev I checked with the admin, we only had a policy that had nothing to do with the refresh token, we even removed that policy but the token expired again after 1 day, we got this error code [https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700081](https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700081)

Comment: Ok i looked at the error - it tells that your access token is expired. In such scenario, once you see the access token got expired then you can get the refresh token, make use of it in your application.

Comment: Could you please decode your access token in https://jwt.ms to see what the value of `exp` is? Just want to check how long the expiry time of the access token is.

Comment: @AllenWu I checked the expiry date of the access token and is exactly one hour,

Comment: @Dev I ran a function to refresh the token every 30 min so the token should never expire, I tested this function and it correctly gives me a new access token and refresh token. But somehow the refresh token is only valid for 1 hour.
I will edit the post to show the complete error log

Comment: interesting... this remembers a [related issue with same error](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2219) reported.

Comment: You application is a single page application right? In this case the refresh token is always limited to 24 hours of activity. Each time you refresh the token successfully, you get a new access token and a **new refresh token**. So to avoid this error, you should use the **new refresh token** each time to refresh the access token / refresh token pairs. If you have been using the first refresh token, it will expire in 24 hours, so you get this error.

Comment: @AllenWu the application is an SPA indeed, but I use the refresh token that returns with the new request, I just checked it now and the refresh token I'm using on the second refresh request is completely different from the first one. But still is expiring after 1 day

Comment: Could it be that even if I'm using the new refresh token the session is limited to 24h and requires a new login after that time?

Comment: It seems to make sense. Usually we use implicit flow instead of authorization code grant flow for the SPA application. It will get the access token directly from `/authorize` endpoint. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256743/session-expiring-in-1-hour-due-to-access-token-in-azure-ad-openidconnectauthenti?answertab=votes#tab-top. I think it's recommended way.

Comment: @Dev about that issue you linked, we can't get an interaction required because we are refreshing the tokens with a backend service, the workflow would be:
1- the user logins with the Microsoft account
2- the token is sent to a mail service that fetches the emails he receives and adds them to a system
3- The mail service is in charge of refreshing the token 
This would work if the token expired at 90 days like the documentation says, but if the user has to login again each day is kinda bothersome

Comment: @AllenWu I have read about the implicit flow but it will just change how we first access to the token, right?. We will still need to get an authorization code in order to get the refresh token and it will be limited to the same lifespan

Comment: @oscarrodriguez No. I don't think so. The implicit grant does not provide refresh tokens. We directly get the access token from `/authorize` endpoint. To renew the access token when it is expired in the implicit flow, we can perform the a hidden iframe request and add the prompt parameter and set its value to none so that users not required to enter their credential again. To develop easily, we can use the ADAL library provided by Microsoft for the SPA application. We can renew the token via the `AuthenticationContext.prototype._renewToken` methoed.

Comment: @AllenWu mmmm, I think this solution doesn't work for us because we need to refresh the token in the backend, and we need a refresh token in order to do that

Comment: @AllenWu There is a solution?

Comment: @oscarrodriguez There is a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways around this. You can only change the application type to something other than SPA, for example, Web app.

For the SPA type, it is specially made that the token valid only for 24 hours so that if an attacker steals the `refresh_ token`, he cannot constantly receive a new `access_token` based on the `refresh_token`.

More information about application types:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-app-types

Answer (score 0):

A Microsoft Graph API token typically expires after one hour. To renew the token, you can use the API call acquireTokenSilent().
Here are some other token lifetimes:
Refresh tokens: 24 hours for single page apps and 90 days for other scenarios
Non-persistent session tokens: 24 hours
Persistent session tokens: 90 days
To resolve an expired token, you can:
Manually refresh the token
Set up automatic token refresh in your application
Increase the token's lifespan

Comment: If you're copying ChatGPT, at least check the formatiing after posting...